# How to Connect to an ICOM IC-705 Transceiver Using WiFi and UDP to Send Commands?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, python, radio

I have an [ICOM IC-705](https://www.icomjapan.com/lineup/products/IC-705/) transceiver, and I'm attempting to connect to this device over WiFi to send commands to it via UDP. I have the IP address and UDP port details, but I'm unsure about the exact protocol and process for establishing this communication.

Here's what I know so far:

Device: ICOM IC-705 transceiver IP Address: 192.168.1.100 (example) UDP Port: 50001 (example) Connection Method: WiFi I've tried using Python's socket module to create a UDP client, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track. Here's the code snippet:

```python
import socket

UDP_IP_ADDRESS = "192.168.1.100"
UDP_PORT = 12345

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
message = b"COMMAND_HERE"
client_socket.sendto(message, (UDP_IP_ADDRESS, UDP_PORT))
client_socket.close()
```

I have the following questions:

Is there any specific command format or protocol that I need to follow to communicate with the IC-705?
Are there any examples or documentation that specifically outline how to interface with this device?
Is there a way to test if the connection is successful and the commands are being received?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated, especially if someone has experience working with the ICOM IC-705 or similar transceivers.
Thank you!

Comment: Were you able to find more information on what protocol ICOM is using?

Answer (score 0):

Since a short time I have also an IC-705.

I wrote hundred of lines to communicate with Icom transceivers in Python (succesfully with IC-7300, IC-9700, IC-7100, IC-7410, etc) using Icom CI-V protocol.

I just discover the possibility to communicate over IP (where I am not comfortable)

Perhaps sending CI-V commands like:
"FE FE A4 E0 05 00 80 49 28 FD"
Should the transceiver set to 28.498 MHz

But first off all I need to set up the IC-705 to the correct WLAN configuration.

73
Christian Thomas (F1CIY)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).